# Filter Django object with another object

Tags: python, django

Django 1.11. I have a model `Article`, and another model `ReadArticles`.

```
class Article(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  length = models.IntegerField()

class ReadArticle(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
```

I want to get a list of all articles which have not been read. I am already using `Q`:

```
length_filter = Q(length__lt=5000)
unread_articles = Article.objects.filter(length_filter).all()
```

How to I extend this to exclude all articles whose ID/User combination are in the `read_articles` table?

Comment: Are you looking for articles not read by current user, or not read by anyone?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: yes, not read by the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't declared a customer `related` name, all what should be needed is `.exclude`:

```
Article.objects.filter(length__lt=5000).exclude(readarticle__user=request.user)
```

Comment: Did it list choices in the exception?

Comment: @GluePear that's not possible with the models you've shown us. "To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model." (see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships))

Comment: Yes, it lists id, name and length

Comment: This is the correct answer, unless your models aren't exactly defined as you're showing us.

Comment: @dirkgroten True, I simplified my models

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query, substituting a user object for `<USER TO FILTER FOR>`:

```
Article.objects.exclude(id__in=[ra.article.id for ra in ReadArticle.objects.filter(user=<USER TO FILTER FOR>)])
```

Comment: `id__in=[ra.article.id for ra in ....]` is a bit easier than the double loop. But this will make two queries to the database rather than a single query.

Comment: You could also use `.values("id")` to skip the list comprehension, or probably `id__in=Subquery(ReadArticle.objects.filter(user=<user>).values("id"))` could work as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can exclude `Article` has referred `ReadArticle` objects with current user.

```
Article.objects.filter(
    length__lt=5000,
).exclude(
    readarticle__user=current_user,
)
```

Comment: This would only work if `readarticle` were a field in `Article`, right? Or at least that's what my error message is telling me.

Comment: No,  `readarticle` is a `ReadArticle` class reference, so it check if there any `ReadArticle` models that is connected to `Article` for this `queryset` it shows only `Article` with no `ReadArticle` references.

Comment: this doesn't work because `Article` has no attribute `user`

Comment: Fixed it. Please see change version.

Comment: still wrong, will always return empty queryset. you can't be empty and have a user attribute set at the same time...

Comment: @dirkgroten you are right, I think the only way is to exclude `Article` with `ReadArcticle` with current user.